# QListWidget with multiple row selection that looks like a table

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

How does one create a multiple selection listbox in Qt/C++ that looks like a table?
Picture a table like this:

```
 Sean    Connery
 David   Niven
 George  Lazenby
 Roger   Moore
 Timothy Dalton
 Pierce  Brosnan
 Daniel  Craig
```

such that multiple rows may be selected by clicking on them, but not parts of rows.
Something like this, by clicking on Sean Connery and Roger Moore rows, where ** indicates selection:

```
 **Sean    Connery**
   David   Niven
   George  Lazenby
 **Roger   Moore**
   Timothy Dalton
   Pierce  Brosnan
   Daniel  Craig
```

I am looking at Qt documentation for [QListWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html), but unclear how to do that.

Comment: Isn't [itemClicked](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemClicked) available to use? When you clicked any item you can applied desired process to them.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk, `QListWidget`, which has rows but no columns, how do I format the rows so that it would look like a table?

Comment: Try QTableView/Widget with setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows)

Comment: @Michael Yeah as you said it doesn't support columns but just cos of curiosity why dont you switch to [QTableWidget](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html)

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk, I want user click to select entire rows, not individual cells. I didn't realize that one could setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows) as Frank Osterfeld suggested.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, thanks!